# Scala work with multiple futures

Tags: scala, akka

I have two source of data which returns `List[Int]`

```
// first work with postgresql database

object Db {

  def get: Future[List[Int]] = // impl

}
// second it's remote service
object Rs {
  def get: Future[List[Int]] = // impl
}
```

And then i want to return two lists. But i do not know how to dealing with exceptions:

1. Db possible throw ConnectionUnavailable
2. Remote service - Bad Request, or InternalServer error
3. Both - TimeoutException

But, when i have only results from db, i want to return it. If i have results from db and from remote service i want to return sum of two lists.

How to work with this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val total: Future[Int] =
  Db.get.flatMap { dbResults =>
    Rs.get.map { remoteResults =>
      dbResults.sum + remoteResults.sum
    }
  }
```

or equivalently

```
   val total: Future[Int] = for {
     dbResults <- Db.get
     remoteResults <- Rs.get
   } yield dbResults.sum + remoteResults.sum
```

I explicitly annotated the result type for the sake of clarity but it's not necessary.

`total` is a `Future[Int]` holding either a successful or a failed computation. If you need to handle errors you can attach a `onFailure` handler on it. For instance

```
total.onFailure {
  case e: TimeoutException => // ...
  case e: ConnectionError  => // ...
}
```

(the names of the exceptions are made up)

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `flatMap` and `recover`:

```
for {
  db <- Db.get
  rs <- Rs.get.recover { 
    case e =>
      logger.error("Error requesting external service", e)
      List.fill(db.length)(0)
  }
} yield (db, rs).zipped.map(_+_).sum
```

You can tweak the transformations if you like (I assumed that you meant element-wise sum of lists), but the basic idea stays the same - if you want to "ignore" the failure of some future, you need to call `recover` on it.

If you want, you can extract the recovering function from the `for` comprehension, but `recover` still has to be called inside of it:

```
def handler(n: Int): PartialFunction[Throwable, List[Int]] = {
  case e =>
    logger.error("Error requesting external service", e)
    List.fill(n)(0)
}

for {
  db <- Db.get
  rs <- Rs.get.recover(handler(db.length))
} yield (db, rs).zipped.map(_+_).sum
```

Comment: The result will be the failed future.

Comment: many thanks. Is it possible handle this error outside of `for`? some like `val sum = for { ... } yield ... 
sum.recover {

}

Comment: @lito, which error do you mean exactly? The one from `Rs.get` or the one from the whole `for`? If the former, then no, you need to handle it directly at the future - the most you can do is to extract the partial function which is passed to `recover`, the method itself still needs to be called there. If the latter, then you need to do it outside of `for` anyway: `val f = for { ... } yield ...; f.recover { ... }`.